# how to get pan number details using soap web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jsp, soap

I am using https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/PanWS.wsdl
this wsdl for getting pan number details.

i am getting

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: You are not authorized to access this request, Please contact DIT administrator
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:129)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.getPanInfo(Unknown Source)
    at text.PanDetails.main(PanDetails.java:28)
Java Result: 1
```

this error

Please tell me any solution for this problems

Comment: ur error telling everyting..u don't have permission to make that request.U need credential for that.By the way why u tagged with both rest and soap tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The credentials you are using are not valid as the error is saying clearly.
Try to login with those credentials and check whether they works or not.

Their [Web Services User Manual](https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/eFiling/Portal/WebServices_Manual.pdf) says

> Retrieve PAN Information - This web service can be used to retrieve
>   pan information for the PAN mentioned. This is applicable for External
>   Agency users.
>
> The user id and password are required for authenticating the user.
>   Once authenticated, then the user will be authorised to invoke the Web
>   service.
>
> where
>
> - **userName - Valid e-Filing User ID**
> - **password - Valid e-Filing password for the User**